# Use keyboard emoticons from Jelly Bean at KitKat

Tags: emoticons

[image: Emoticons JellyBean]

How i can put at my KitKat Nexus4?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is this question flagged as unclear? Seems pretty clear to me - How do you use those emoticons on a Nexus 4 running Kit Kat (especially for messaging, since that seems to be where they are used)?

Comment: I haven't flagged it but it is unclear to me, as different apps render different emoticons when the base text versions are used i.e. ;) etc. If you use hangouts there are built in emoji, but if I text with ;) I get one picture in hangouts, a different one in Samsung's own SMS app a totally different one again in HTC's own SMS app. So the answer is "it depends." I'm aware it is a nexus, but the default now is technically hangouts and that has it's own emoji option beside the Text Entry Box (where you type) that replaces the keyboard with emoji board (or whatever you would call it)